# I'm having issues with move_uploaded_file() function

Tags: php, html

I have problem with moving uploaded file to my local server. The form seems to execute php part but uploaded file is not being moved. Please help.

The code I'm using is:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="file">
   <input type ="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_FILES['file'])){
    $tempName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $dest = __DIR__.'\pic'."\\".$tempName;
    echo $dest;
    $skuska = move_uploaded_file($tempName,$dest);
}
?>
```

Comment: Use the *nix `/` instead of the dos `\\` PHP will automatically fix it for whichever OS it is running on

Comment: Then use `$tempName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];` as that is where the temp file is temporarily stored, `$_FILES['file']['name']` is just the name it was called on the user system

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php